# Why does my kernel fail to build?

Tags: kernel, compiling

So I am a Linux noob, but I am still working on getting my Intel tablet working with all the devices, this is very much a learning experience for me. Plan in the end is to just have a bootable image that can be installed. Final goal I wish is to have Ubuntu touch, so thats why I am working with Ubuntu. (I don't know if Ubuntu Touch will turn out great, but I need to have a goal right (-; ) This is the [Github page](https://github.com/Manouchehri/vi8) I (and another guy) are using for documentation. Now I am trying to compile my own kernel to add the touchscreen driver, and also try to add the bluetooth controller to rfkill because the wifi/bluetooth driver does not get the bluetooth up and running. I am doing it in Virtualbox on my desktop since i have a 6 core 4.3Ghz Overclocked watercooled CPU, and the tablet has an atom processor (quad, 1.8Ghz but not all Ghz are created equal ;P). I use the same Ubuntu Iso file in Virtualbox as on the tablet.
These are the steps I do to compile, first get the source

```
 sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-`uname -r`
 sudo apt-get install libncurse5
 apt-get source linux-image-`uname -r`
```

Okay, gonna add the touchscreen driver now. This driver was suggested to me to try by a guy that wrote another (not this one) touchscreen driver.

```
 cd linux-4.2.0/driver/input/touchscreen/
 patch < ~/silead.patch
```

Now to add my device to rfkill, a guy that have the same chipset had to do this to get the wifi/bluetooth driver to work with bluetooth.

```
cd ~/linux-4.2.0/net/rfkill/
patch < ~/rfkill-gpio.patch
```

Now I'm gonna clean, and IDK why but run mrproper and prepare. I get a yes when it asks about the silead driver.

```
cd ~/linux-4.2.0/
make clean
make mrproper
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
make prepare
```

Then I select load and load the .config file and save it again to see if there are any errors with the config.

```
fakeroot make-kpkg -j11 --initrd --append-to-version=-vi8-test kernel_image kernel_headers
```

[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12602433) is the output which fails here.

```
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target 'ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/VBoxGuest-linux.o' failed
scripts/Makefile.build:403: recipe for target 'ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest' failed
scripts/Makefile.build:403: recipe for target 'ubuntu/vbox' failed Makefile:959: recipe for target 'ubuntu' failed
```

I am at a loss here, I dont know what I am doing :(

Comment: One thing you're doing is not posting the commands you type, AND their output (did the `patch` commands suceed or fail?). There is probably some earlier error message that is meaningful. For example `Makefile:959: recipe for target 'ubuntu' failed`. What do `Makefile` line 959, and `scripts/Makefile.build`, lines 258 and 403 say? Before building a kernel with changes, it is always safer to build an unchanged kernel. This will let you tell if your changes broke the build.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for your feedback. I've now tried to compile on another machine and vanilla with no changes. [output of the make-kpkg command](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12610439/) Looks very much the same to me.


[This is what the Makefile looks like around line 959](http://imgur.com/cTsLQ8Q)  
[This is what scripts/Makefile.build looks like around line 258](http://imgur.com/Ndu0h4U)  
[This is what scripts/Makefile.build looks like around line 403](http://imgur.com/D7cyH8y)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The resolution to my problem, which was an acceptable solution for me was to pull the kernel source from git instead. This compiled just fine, I don't know why the `apt-get source` fetched source did not.